# How to send notifications to all commentors on polymorphic comments in rails?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, orm, ruby-on-rails-5

I am using polymorphic association for comments.
I want to send notification to all user who comments on post.

- Suppose **user1** posted a post.
- **User2** comments on it.
- **User1** gets
  notification (users = User.joins(:posts).where(:posts => {id: params[:post_id]})) that "*User2 posted a comment*"
- Again, **User1** comments.
- Now, **User2** should get a notification (users= ????)
- If **user2, user3, user4** comments then all the related users should get notifications.

**comment.rb**

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to  :user
    belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true
    has_many :comments, as: :commentable
    validates :comment, presence: true

    after_create :notifications
    def notifications
       #Create Notification             
       users =  ????
       (users-[@current_user]).each do |user|
        Resque.enqueue(NotifyJob, Notification.create(
        recipient: user,
        actor: @current_user,
        action: "posted",
        notifiable: @comment))
        end
    end

end
```

**user.rb**

```
 class User < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
   has_many :comments, as: :commentable, dependent: :destroy
   has_many :notifications, foreign_key: :recipient_id, dependent: :destroy
 end
```

**post.rb**

```
 class Post < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    validates :comment, presence: true
    validates :user_id, presence: true
    has_many :comments, as: :commentable
 end
```

**comments_controller.rb**

```
module Api 
module V1
    class CommentsController < ApplicationController
        skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
        before_action :authorize_request
        before_action :find_commentable

        def new
            @comment = Comment.new
        end

        def create
            @comment = @commentable.comments.new(comment_params)
            @comment.user = @current_user

            if @comment.save
                render json: @comment, status: :created

            else
                render json: { errors: @comment.errors.full_messages },
                status: :unprocessable_entity
            end
        end

        def show
            @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
            if !@comment.nil?
                render json: @comment, status: :ok
            else
                render json: {errors: @comment.errors.full_messages}, status: :unprocessable_entity
            end
        end

        private

        def comment_params
            params.permit(:comment)
        end

        def find_commentable
            @commentable = Comment.find_by_id(params[:comment_id]) if params[:comment_id]
            @commentable = Post.find_by_id(params[:post_id]) if params[:post_id]
        end
    end
end
end
```

Comment: You using a lot of bad ideas. Create some sort of subscription table (user_id, post_id) and check it. Also move code out of controller for example to model's after_create callback

Comment: @VyacheslavLoginov Thanks, Now I have edited my model and comment controller. Can you help??

Comment: Why the comment `has_many :comments, as: :commentable`? It is comments tree?

Comment: I'm not sure if polymorphic relationship approach is the best way here. Why not simply do `has_many :comments` for User and Post? Then just query users who have commented specific post and exclude current comment author (User) and send notifications.

Comment: @Vasilisa yes, it's nested comment tree.

Comment: @matiss It's working fine as it's nested tree. But we have to add notification feature on it. I completed almost all but I got stuck on this part only. (I don't know much about ORM /Query on rails).

Comment: Because comments acts as tree, just help me to find relationship between comment1 and comment2 of post?

Comment: If I commented a comment (I created nested comment), should all users, who commented the whole post, be notificated, or just those, who commented parent comment? I mean, how deep should we go up in the tree to send notifications?

Comment: @Vasilisa We are not going deep. For now we just want to notify who comments on post, which acts like leaf only. Did you get it?? I just want : SELECT user_id from comments where commentable_id = post_id; But in ORM form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't make much changes. I just made changes like this on:

**comment.rb**

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to  :user
   belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true
   has_many :comments, as: :commentable
   validates :comment, presence: true

   private
   after_commit :create_notifications, on: [:create]
   #Create Notification
   def create_notifications 
     commentable = self.commentable 
     commentors= Comment.where(commentable: commentable).pluck(:user_id)
     users = User.find(commentors)-[self.user]
       users.each do |user|    
         Resque.enqueue(NotifyJob, Notification.create(
         actor: self.user,
         recipient: user,
         action: "posted",
         notifiable: self.commentable))
       end
   end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Your first problem is in `User` model. You have

```rb
has_many :comments, as: :commentable, dependent: :destroy
```

but `Comment` model `belongs_to  :user` and have `user_id`, it means that in `User` should be

```
has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
```

In this case you can get all user comments easily with `User.first.comments`

The second one is callback. Vyacheslav Loginov is right about bad practice to put this complex logic inside the controller action, but callbacks are not good practice too. Not sure which of them is worse. You will create notification on every comment creation, even from console. Notifications will be created in every test setup where you create commnets. Not sure if that it is what you really want.

Better option is to create separate ServiceObject to handle notifications

```rb
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @comment = @commentable.comments.new(comment_params)
    @comment.user = @current_user

    if @comment.save
      NotificationSender.new(@comment).comment_notification
      render json: @comment, status: :created
    else
      render json: { errors: @comment.errors.full_messages },
      status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end
end

class NotificationSender
  def initialize(resource)
    @resource = resource
  end

  # you can add here all other notifications as methods
  def comment_notification
    users = User.where(id: @resource.commentable.comments.pluck(:user_id)).
                 where.not(id: @resource.user_id)
    users.each do |user|
      Resque.enqueue(
        NotifyJob, 
        Notification.create(
          recipient: user,
          actor: @resource.user,
          action: "posted",
          notifiable: @resource
        )
      )
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot.  I already solved it. I was confused in association. 
And thanks again, I was writing create_notification for many model , rewriting same code and changing  per requirement. But I can now use resource  for those models.

Comment: like for `NotificationSender.new(@comment).comment_notification` :)

Comment: @susie happy to help you! :)